# How to add and use a resource from a custom package/component in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to make a component that uses some resources compiled in my **package's project**. My component will try to use this resource (a PNG image) during runtime (at its constructor).

I want to use it in my **application's project**, but as soon as the component gets created, I get the following exception:

```
First chance exception at $7579B9BC. Exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource xxx not found'. Process yyy.exe (6060)
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

The calling code for the resource in the **package's project** is like this:

```
Png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'png_resource_name');
```

**EDIT 2**

As suggested by David, I tried using the function GetModuleHandle, but it will always return 0 if I call it from the **package's project** or the **application's project**. The code being called in the **package's project** is like this:

```
PackageModuleHandle := GetModuleHandle(PChar('my_package.bpl'));
Png := TPngImage.Create;
Png .LoadFromResourceName(PackageModuleHandle, 'png_resource_name');
```

Absolute paths to the bpl file won't work either.

**EDIT 3**

New attempt based on new answer:

```
PackageModuleHandle := FindClassHInstance(TMyComponent);
Png := TPngImage.Create;
Png .LoadFromResourceName(PackageModuleHandle, 'png_resource_name');
```

Fails with the same exception.

**EDIT 4**

Using ResourceHacker, and if I used it right, the resources doesn't seem to be in my bpl file. What could I be doing wrong about this? Seems such a complicated matter to such a simple feature.

**CONCLUSION**

I had to add the .res file of my package to the package's .dpr just after the {$R *.res} line. Like this:

```
{$R *.res}
{$R 'my_pacakge.res'}
```

Also, I had to include the my_package.rc file to my project, so the resources would get compiled to the .res after each build. That did the trick, I guess. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: When you say "Fails with same exception" do you mean that. The file name reported is the .exe file?

Comment: It won't load my resource. It gives the "Resource not found" exception as stated in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Does it report the .exe file name, or does it report the .bpl file name?

Comment: Its the exact same message as written in the question.

Comment: This is a bit of a train wreck of a question now.  ;-)  If the resources are not present in the .bpl then you need to look at the location where they are added. You have a `{$R resfile.res}` presumably.

Comment: @WarrenP That's bad advice. Resources can be added to packages and can easily be loaded from them. Better to solve the problem correctly.

Comment: @WarrenP No, you find the module using the code that Remy provided. And that can be either an exe or a package depending on how you deploy the app. Remy explains it nicely.

Comment: I see that you have now accepted an answer. Could you let us know how you resolved the problem. Having spent so much time on this I'd like to know.

Comment: Post your `.RC` file and specify where you've added the `{$R xxx}`  declaration please, haole.

Comment: David; Agreed. Remy right, Warren wrong. Fixed my answer to acknolwedge Remy.

Comment: The remaining point that I contend I've got right is that by having the {$R} declaration in the Unit instead of the project, you avoid customers of your component from having to add the {$R} declaration to their apps when they have statically linked and have no BPLs. Think of it as a dependency that you could forget to add to your application, and since users of your component won't know about the dependency, `FindClassHInstance` is not sufficient, even though it's necessary.

Comment: I think the main conclusion here is that you need to be more careful in your debugging. When you said that `GetModuleHandle` was returning 0, that was clearly not true. It's really important to take your time and get the details right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was true. But that wasn't the only problem that was keeping me from achieving my goal. FindHInstance returns a correct handle and GetModuleHandle doesn't, in my context. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, `GetModuleHandle` works when you pass the correct file name (you must not have been doing so). That's a truly fundamental part of Windows. It works. But it is true that `FindClassHInstance` is the right approach.

Comment: I've tried both the bpl name and the complete absolute path as shown in ProcessExplorer and neither worked. :(

Comment: What is the class name to provide to FindClassHInstance? I get some similar issue with a non-graphical class using a resource in a bpl. When using the custom-editor, it works the first time, and fail the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `FindClassHInstance()`, specifying your component's class type, instead of using the global `HInstance` variable or `GetModuleHandle()`. That way, you obtain the correct module handle regardless of whether the package gets statically linked or dynamically linked into the main executable.

Comment: +1 That's a better way to do it I agree, but I still can't understand why `GetModuleHandle` could fail.

Comment: FindClassHInstance succeeds getting the handle, but Delphi is throwing the same exception. The resource is there (on the package's project) and all the names are right. I've tested with png data and bmp data and I get the same results.

Comment: Next step after confirming that the resource is in the package project is to confirm that it's in the compiled package. Check whether the resource is in the BPL file. And make sure the BPL file you check is the same one your application is loading — that there aren't two copies of your BPL floating around.

Comment: How do I check if the resource is in the BPL file? I've confirmed that the resource is indeed in the .res file. And there is only ony of "my_package.bpl" file loaded in the ProcessExplorer.

Comment: Use a resource editor like XN Resource Editor or ResourceHacker

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `HInstance`, the handle of the executable module to the resource loading function. That fails because the resource lives in the package module. Therefore you need to pass the module handle for the package. You can obtain the module handle of the package like this:

```
PackageModuleHandle := GetModuleHandle(PChar('MyPackage.bpl'));
```

If you are loading your package dynamically then the call to `LoadPackage` returned the module handle.

**Update**: Remy's suggestion of using `FindClassHInstance` is clearly a better way to obtain the module handle.

Comment: I'm using HInstance in my package's code. I'll edit and add that line.

Comment: @haole Yes, I assumed the code in question lived in the package. My mistake. Answer should get you home now.

Comment: Almost there: The function GetModuleHandle always returns 0, no mather if I try MyPackage.bpl, just MyPackage or the absolute path of the bpl. What else could be wrong? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` works. I guess you must somehow be passing the wrong name, somehow. You are replacing MyPackage.bpl with the name of your package.

Comment: I'm sure `GetModuleHandle` works. I'd load up Process Explorer use that to check the name of the modules in your process. Find your package in Process Explorer lower pane and use that name when you call `GetModuleHandle`.

Answer (score 2):

A component that uses a resource that is implemented in a unit called `MyUnit1.pas` should include the following line inside:

```
{$R MyUnitRc.res MyUnitRc.rc}
```

Note that the above syntax won't work on some old delphi versions (Delphi 7). The above works on 2010,XE,XE2 and so on, and it compiles the .rc into a .res when the project builds that unit.  Alternatively you would add the `{$R}` declaration to each statically linked application and also to your BPL's .dpr file.

That .RC file `mYUnitRc.res` will contain one or more lines declaring your resources.  I use RCDATA declarations to load PNGs, like this:

```
MYIMAGENAME RCDATA "MyFile.png"
```

If you do it this way, instead of using an RC file added to the .dproj/.dpr only, then it will work in two important cases:

1. When the BPL is loading at designtime.
2. When the component is loading at runtime from within an application that is compiled with Runtime Packages turned off.

To handle the third case, the one that the other answers (Remy and David) deal with, you do need to call FindClassHinstance as Remy stated. However I believe you should also look at how you are including the resource file and having it compiled and linked, both within your package, and within applications that use the component.

Here is some sample code showing loading a resource at runtime into a TPngImage, that I use in my own components:

```
procedure TSampleControl.LoadImageFromResource( button:TSubControl);
var
    png:TPngImage;
begin
  if button.DefaultResourceId='' then exit;
      png := TPngImage.Create;
      try
        try
        png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,button.DefaultResourceId);
          button.Glyph.Assign(png);
        except
          on E:Exception do begin
               OutputDebugString( PChar(button.DefaultResourceId+' load error:'+E.Message) );

          end;

        end;
      finally
        png.Free;
      end;

end;
```

Note that I catch resource load exceptions, which leave some elements in my control without their glyphs but at least does not crash Delphi.  `HInstance` may need to be changed as David and Remy Point out to use `LoadFromResourceName` to handle the case where you need to load from the .BPL but I don't think that you can assume that a person who uses your components is always going to redistribute your `BPL` file, and thus `FindClassHinstance` is preferable to `GetModuleHandle`..

**Update:** I should have used what Remy suggested:

```
       png.LoadFromResourceName( FindClassHInstance(TSampleControl),
                 button.DefaultResourceId);
```