# How to store a large text in a Delphi component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I made a custom component that needs a rather large (say 1MB) UTF8 text to function. For development purposes, I just loaded this from a file. Now I want to get rid of that file. What is the easiest way to store its contents in the component, such that the user of the component needn't bother with this?

First I tried making it string constant, but soon Delphi started to complain in many different ways (too long or too many, out of memory, etc.). When I switched to embedding it as a resource, I found that the resource will not be automatically compiled into the actual application as well, so it's not transparent to the component user...

## Update

I got it working if I create a resource file myself, which I manually add to the unit. Then, I still need a pre-build event for it to be actual. The question remains why it doesn't work if I add it to the package, via the Delphi menu, rather than to the unit. And why `{$R myresource.res myresource.rc}` doesn't compile it automatically as it should...?

## Update 2

Apparently the resource script needs to be added to the project for automatic compilation to work.

Comment: How did you add it as a resource? It should work fine that way, and be put into the resource table of the application (presuming that the resource can be found at the time the application is built).

Comment: @KenWhite Just went to `Project`, `Resources...` and added the file to the component project. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9824396/1163893 made me believe it is never going to work this way without doing something with the application project as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the `{$R myresource.res}` line in the unit containing the component should work.

You can add the `myresource.rc` file to the component's package to make Delphi generate `myresource.res` automatically.

Comment: I added the file to the component project via the menu as described in my comment above. In the `dpk` I have `{$R *.res}`. If I add `{$R <project-name>.res}` to the unit as well, I get warnings about duplicate resources and it still doesn't work. If, instead, I create another `rc` myself, it is not automatically compiled to `res`.

Comment: `{$R MyText.res MyText.rc}` doesn't solve that either; error remains the same.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: Stop trying to associate the resource with the **project**. It's not part of a project; it's part of your component. There's no need for a pre-build event or anything else, if you include it with your component properly as a resource using a proper resource script. It will get compiled and linked automatically whenever your unit is used in a project.

Comment: @KenWhite How should I understand "include properly"? What else should I do than creating the `rc` and adding that line to the unit, to have it be compiled automatically?

Comment: @KenWhite Already got it; added it to the project and now it's fine.

Comment: If you add the fact that `MyText.rc` needs to be added to the project, your answer is acceptable.