# How to load resources in a FMX-component

Tags: delphi, resources, components, firemonkey

I try to use resources in a FMX-Component and get the EResNotFound-Error when I try to read the resource.

following scenario:

- a FMX-bpl (FmxComponents.bpl) where i added some png-files in my IDE (XE7) over 'resources and images'.
- the resources are into the 'FmxComponents.dres' but not in 'FmxComponents.res'.
- when I try to exceute this statement `TResourceStream.Create(FindClassHInstance(TPmFmxTitelbar), 'ImgOptions', RT_RCDATA);` I get the error EResNotFound 'resource ImgOptions not found'
- I tryed to solve it with the post from haole ([how-to-add-and-use-a-resource-from-a-custom-package-component-in-delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824396/how-to-add-and-use-a-resource-from-a-custom-package-component-in-delphi)) but with no success.

Comment: Why are you using `FindClassHInstance`? Don't you want to put the `TResourceStream.Create` call in the module to which the resources are linked, and pass `HInstance`?

Comment: thanks, good hint. I thought HInstance gives me the handle from the mainUnit.

Comment: Yeah, that's a misthink on my part. No good for packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved this problem.
I added the 'FmxComponents.dres' to my component with `{$R FmxComponents.dres}`.

I thought that it is enough to add this in the dpk-file.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `TResourceStream` constructor is the instance of the module which is searched for the resources. So, if you've really linked the resources correctly, using the correct type and name, then one would assume that you are passing the wrong module instance.

So, perhaps the module that implements the misspelled `TPmFmxTitelbar` is not the module to which the resources are linked.

If you really are passing the right module instance, then the remaining conclusion is that you are failing to link resources with the specified type and name. Use a resource viewer/editor to check that.